# Using GET method when I already have a ? in my Querystring

Tags: php, forms, get

This seems like a simple to answer question, but I cannot figure out how to do it, or if it is even possible.

I am building a search bar so users can search offers on a website. It works using the `POST` method, but it doesn't update the Querystring, and I want users to be able to see what they have searched, so I must use the `GET` method.

My url is set up as follows:

`http://mysitename.com/index.php?rs=offers`

The `?rs=offers` defines being on the offer page. Without the `?rs=` it registers as accessing the index.php file directly, and gives an error. It's like an anti hack thing.

What I am wanting to know is how I can start the `GET` method after the `?rs=offers` so it reads something like this:

`http://mysitename.com/index.php?rs=offers&find=whatisearched`

right now it looks like this:

`http://mysitename.com/index.php?find=whatisearched`

Which gives the error I described above.

This is the current form layout as well so you can see if there is something in it that I may have defined wrong.

```
<form method='get' action='index.php?rs=offers'>
    <table class='offers'>
<tr>
    <th>Search All Offers</th>
</tr>
<tr> 

    <td>

      <input type='text' name='find' maxlength='255' style='width:200px' value='' />

      <input type='submit' value='Search' />

    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<form method='get' action='index.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='rs' value='offers' />
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

Comment: Wow you have no idea how stupid I feel now -_-.. guess I didn't think about it long enough! Thanks Matt!

Comment: @kira423 Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes.